# The number of connected components of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ which keep $x^2 - y^2$ invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Working on yet another past comprehensive exam question.

> Let $S$ be the set of real $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$, keeping invariant the form $x^2 - y^2$. Regard $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$. How many connected components does $S$ have in the induced topology?

First note that

$$f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2 = [x\quad y]\left[\begin{array}\
1 &\ \ 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}\
x\\
y
\end{array}\right].$$

So $A \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ preserves $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$ if and only if $A^T\operatorname{diag}(1, -1)A = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$. Now setting

$$A = \left[\begin{array}\
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right]$$

we obtain the three equations $a^2 - c^2 = 1$, $ab -cd = 0$, and $b^2 - d^2 = -1$, as well as the determinant condition $ad - bc = 1$. I don't think manipulating these equations will help here though.

Any hints about how to calculate the number of connected components of $S = \{A \in SL(2, \mathbb{R}) \mid A^T\operatorname{diag}(1, -1)A = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1)\}$ would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should get more information about SL(2,R). this subgroup(of GL(2,R)) has two connected components corresponding to det=+1 and det=-1 . Moreover there is a classification of them with its decomposition. I think the things you learned in this field,plus the information of SL(2,R) connected components and SL(2,R) decomposition would help you to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your relations are correct, one obtains $2$ connected components:

$t\rightarrow (a=\epsilon\cosh (t),b=\sinh (t),c=\sinh (t),d=\epsilon\cosh (t))$ where $\epsilon=\pm 1$.